# Cant figure out how to make the picture inside a div not to be cut when u make the window smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all i started learning HTML/CSS with Bootstrap 3 this is my 3rd day and i kinda have a problem and i dont know how to fix it.

I tryed a few things that i found on the internet like makeing it responsive for mobile and tablets screens so it changes its size but it was more like a fail.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

P.S: I didnt make this post as it should be because i can post only 1 link.

I took out the Dropox link and i put this instead

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2739/

Thx for telling me abou JSFiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <head>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

            <title>Title</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
            <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 1024px)">>
    </head>
    <body id="bd">

            <div id="navbar"class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top ">
                    <div class = "container">

                            <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Your Title Goest Here</a>

                            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

                            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                                            <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Who are we </a></li>
                                            <li><a href = "#">Our products</a></li>
                                            <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href = "#">F.A.Q</a></li>

                                    </ul>

                            </div>

                    </div>
            </div>

        <div id = "a1" >
            <a  href="#bd" class = "btn btn-info pull-right " id="buttonTop">Go Up</a>
            <div id = "whoarewe">

            </div>  


        </div>  



    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">

        <div class = " container ">
            <a href = "http://www.google.ro" class = "navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Grab Your Gift</a>
            <p class = "navbar-text pull-right">Do not miss our 10% off gift !</p>

        </div>

    </div>





    </body>


<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Provide jsFiddle, none is going to open your .rar archive.

Comment: Paste your code here what you have tried

Comment: Ty for telling me about JSFiddle this is it.                                  http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2739/ Try makeing the window smaller and u'll see that the circle gets cut.

Comment: Another solution is to add `background-size:100% auto` on `#whoarewe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `background-size: contain;` to your `#whoarewe` style.

Comment: Ty it worked, thanks a lot for the help and fast answer.